# Initialize array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have struct Node in my code defined like this:

```
struct Node {
Node() : prev(0), left(0), right(0) {}
Node* prev;
Node* left;
Node* right;
char val;
};
```

I initialize array of Node structer objects like that:

```
Node** pool = new Node*[10000000];
```

I thought it will create Node structure objects using defoult constructor, but in fact the arrays seems to be empty. Is there any EFFICIENT way to create immidiately array of 'empty' objects?

Comment: You're not creating Node objects in that line, you're creating Node* (all of which (outside of Debug) are likely to point to random bits of memory).

Comment: you never want to use 'new' within a C++ program.

Comment: You will need to profile accessing your node pool versus allocating nodes from dynamic memory.  IMHO, the performance gain from using a node pool is insignificant.  Usually node pools are used by memory constrained systems like embedded systems.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector); there is very little reason to use `new` in C++.

```
 auto pool = std::vector<Node>(10000000);
```

(Your original code is creating `Node*`s, not `Node`s.)

---

If for some reason you don't want to use `vector`, you could use [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).  That code would be

```
std::unique_ptr<Node[]> pool(new Node[10000000]);
```

but you *really* should use `vector`.

---

Also, you can simplify and improve `Node`:

```
struct Node final {
Node* prev = nullptr;
Node* left = nullptr;
Node* right = nullptr;
char val = '\0';

Node(const Node&) = delete;
Node& operator(const Node&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: i upvote Dan's answer. Anyway, what are you trying to do? it looks like you are trying to create an xml parser. Check out on the web for existing libraries.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUjpw.png

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to use "new" in C++. I work on projects where we don't even use the standard library for many reasons...

Answer (score 0):

If you are constructing an ast/asg and you do not need linear data structures, you may consider still bulk allocating stuff with an `::std::vector<>`, which will potentially give you cache locality.

You can still link individual `Node` objects via the pointers in your struct. If you then use indices instead of pointers, you can even resize your vector whenever you run out of available objects in your pool.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node** pool = new Node*[10000000];
```

constructs an array of `Node*` rather than `Node`. What you are looking for is,

```
Node* pool = new Node[10000000];
```

which constructs an array of `Node`. If you actually want an array of `Node*` then the appropriate initialisation is,

```
int nObjects = 10000000;
Node** pool = new Node[nObjects];

for(auto i = 0; i < nObjects; ++i) {
    pool[i] = new Node();
}
```

As others have said you likely do not want to use `new` or C-style arrays if you can avoid it.